# How to fix vim textwidth during editing?

Tags: vim, text-editors, word-wrap

When editing files that I limit in my .vimrc to tw=80, when I come back to edit them later, the line-lengths end up all over the place. e.g.

```
lets say for the sake of argument that this line hits 80 characters
there and continues on the next line as normal
```

After editing...

```
lets say for the sake of argument (edit edit edit edit) that this 
line hits 80 characters
there and continues on the next line as normal
```

Instead of

```
lets say for the sake of argument (edit edit edit edit) that this 
line hits 80 characters there and continues on the next line as 
normal
```

**Anyone know what I can do to fix this behaviour?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the "`gq`" normal-mode command to reformat text.  It works on a visual selection, or with a motion.  For example, you can use the text-object "`ap`" (which can be used in place of a motion) which means "a paragraph" (the current paragraph that the cursor is on):

```
gqap
```

Or you could visually select the paragraph(s) you want to reformat and just type "`gq`".

Another trick is to add "a" and optionally "w" to the 'formatoptions' option:

```
:set formatoptions+=aw
```

This will automatically reformat paragraphs as you type, without needing to resort to "`gq`".

See:

```
:help gq
:help auto-format
:help 'formatoptions'
:help motion.txt
```

Comment: :set formatoptions+=aw works PERFECTLY. Probably already saved me a couple of minutes of work just this evening!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is vi formatoptions. To turn on text wrapping:

```
:set fo+= t
```

Sources:

ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf

http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/03/vim-textwidth/